# SQL JSON NULL VALUES

Tags: sql, json, null, nosql

I need to convert the result of the query to a JSON. My query is:

```
**select TABLE2.Id [TABLE2.Id],
    TABLE4.Id  [TABLE4_Record.Id],
    TABLE4.Name as [TABLE4_Record.Name]
from TABLE2
left join TABLE4 on TABLE2.TABLE4ID = TABLE4.Id
where TABLE2.id = 30067
FOR JSON path  ,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES**
```

The result is:

> {"Id":"30667", "TABLE4_Record":{"Id":null,"Name":null}}**

Is there a way that TABLE4_Record returns null instead of the structure

> {"Id":null,"Name":null}?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean getting  `{"Id":"30667", "TABLE4_Record":{}}` ??  Since removing `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` part already removes the element with `TABLE4_Record` key in that case.

Comment: Yes, it may work... is it possible to do it?